# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called

Tags: python, dataframe, constructor

I am trying to create a dataframe with Python, which works fine with the following command:

```
df_test2 = DataFrame(index = idx, data=(["-54350","2016-06-25T10:29:57.340Z","2016-06-25T10:29:57.340Z"]))
```

but, when I try to get the data from a variable instead of hard-coding it into the data argument; eg. :

```
r6 = ["-54350", "2016-06-25T10:29:57.340Z", "2016-06-25T10:29:57.340Z"]
df_test2 = DataFrame(index = idx, data=(r6))
```

I expect this is the same and it should work? But I get:

> ```
> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
> ```

Comment: Try `DataFrame(index=idx, data=r6)`, i.e. get rid of the extra parenthesis.

Comment: Does the first result not cause an error? you have mismatched parenthesis

Comment: That really depends what you have inside `idx`. Also your first example is a `SyntaxError` so that can't work anyway. Then, please provide the exact error that you get. Furthermore please indicate the package which exposes the `DataFrame` object.

Comment: Thank you for the given answers so far, I updated the initial question to remove the SyntaxError (copy/pasted some whitespaces and missing parenthesis). I haven't gone into detail (yet) because I want to keep complexity out of the question as I don't understand it should read it as a string ; just as in the working example without the variable?

Comment: In my case idx = idx = Int64Index(counter) and counter = list(range(0,3)) . Package I am using is pandas (from pandas import *) , exact error:  File "C:\XXX\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 422, in __init__
    raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! . Tried to get rid of the extra parenthesis but didn't solved the error.

Comment: if arr.ndim == 0 and index is not None and columns is not None:
                values = cast_scalar_to_array((len(index), len(columns)),
                                              data, dtype=dtype)
                mgr = self._init_ndarray(values, index, columns,
                                         dtype=values.dtype, copy=False)
            else:
                raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')

Comment: Just found the solution, it seems a string representation isn't satisfying enough for the DataFrame constructor, I did a import ast and converted it to a dict (dict = ast.literal_eval(r6) and used it as input --> df_test2 = DataFrame(index = idx, data=(dict)) which solved the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for the error:

It seems a string representation isn't satisfying enough for the DataFrame constructor

Fix/Solutions:

```
import ast
# convert the string representation to a dict
dict = ast.literal_eval(r6) 
# and use it as the input
df_test2 = DataFrame(index = idx, data=(dict))
```

which will solve the error.